# How to check if angular js popover is opened and focus inside template

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I have an angular js uib popover. How do I focus inside the template's input box when it opens?

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-default text-left" uib-popover-template="'form.html'" popover-trigger="'outsideClick'">Assign Users</a>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="form.html">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">Users</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text">
   </div>
</script>
```

Comment: add `autofocus` attribute

Comment: You can check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e9yqyas1/